# Como bloquear rolagem de formulário quando estou arrastando um controle?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um formulário onde desenho a rede de fornecimento de uma empresa. Para isso, preciso permitir que o usuário mova os controles que estão no formulário.

Isso está funcionando.

Contudo, quando o usuário move o controle para além da posição atual do form, o form aumenta de tamanho e rola (direita, esquerda, pra cima ou para baixo), e o controle que está sendo arrastado é levado mais longe, o que faz com que o formulário role mais, e assim por diante.

O formulário continua rolando, talvez aumentando de tamanho, até que o usuário solte o botão do mouse.

Para corrigir isso, preciso impedir a rolagem do formulário quando estiver movendo o controle. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Pela resposta de [Loathing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513432/1387277) no SOen:

Você pode evitar que o formulário role usando esse código, sobrescrevendo o método `ScrollToControl`:

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    Point pt = this.AutoScrollPosition;
    return pt;
}
```